# View layer of child still showing previous value of parent table column departmentID ,but parent is deleted

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

i am stuck on problem i have made a normal project using spring MVC and spring-data in which i have dao layer,service layer ,controller and view layer. In this project i have `Department, employee,employeeproject` table.  When i delete the department corresponding Employee table column `departmentId` is set to null.so this is properly reflected in database when in delete the department from UI ,but when i again see the employee through `getALlEmployee` button then at that time previous value of department is still showing in the UI instead of value is null in database. When i restart the server then value is not showing why this is so ?

this is my function getAllEmployee() in all three layer

In DAO layer

```
   /**
     * Get the all employee detail from the database
     * 
     * @return list of employees
     */
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll(new Sort(
                Direction.ASC, "employeeNumber"));

        return employeeList;
    }
```

in service layer

```
    @Override
    public List<EmployeeBO> getAllEmployees() {
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOList = null;
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
        if (employeeList != null && employeeList.size() != 0) {
            employeeBOList = new ArrayList<EmployeeBO>();
            for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
                employeeBOList.add(convertEmployeeEntityToBO(employee));
            }
        }

     return employeeBOList;
```

and in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetAllEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAllEmployee(
        @ModelAttribute("employeeBO") EmployeeBO employeeBO) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List<EmployeeBO> list = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    modelAndView.addObject("employeeBO", employeeBO);
    modelAndView.addObject("listEmployeeBO", list);
    modelAndView.setViewName("EmployeeList");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

department class pozo

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department extends BaseObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private String departmentId;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_LOCATION")
    private String departmentLocation;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Collection<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

employee pozo class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends BaseObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
    private long employeeNumber;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private String departmentId;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_NUMBER")
    private long mobileNumber;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Collection<EmployeeProject> employeeProjectList = new ArrayList<EmployeeProject>();
```

these two class dept and employee pozo classes have setter getter

repository interface of department

```
    import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.Department;

/**
 * Repository interface for {@link Department} instances. Provides basic CRUD
 * operations due to the extension of {@link JpaRepository}. Includes custom
 * implemented functionality by extending {@link JpaRepository}.
 * 
 * @author ankurj
 */
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, String> {
    /**
     * Find all Department with the given department Name. This method will be
     * translated into a query by constructing it directly from the method name
     * as there is no other query declared.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            departmentName to be find
     * @return list of departments
     */
    public List<Department> findByDepartmentNameLike(String name);

    /**
     * 
     * update the employee with the given departmentId. This method will be
     * translated into a query using the one declared in the {@link Query}
     * annotation declared one.
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            departmentId to be set
     * @param deptId
     *            departmentId is to deleted
     * @return integer value
     */
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Employee set DEPARTMENT_ID = :departmentId WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = :deptId")
    public int updateEmployeeDepartmentId(
            @Param("departmentId") String departmentId,
            @Param("deptId") String deptId);
}
```

Comment: Are you re-loading the employee data?  Are you using some caching mechanism, like EhCache, maybe through Hibernate?  If you are re-calling getAllEmployee, are you sure it's actually running again?

Comment: `@CodeChimp not sure when i run it through cmd then everytime i get the correct value cause every time getAllEmployee() execute and every time hibernate class is loaded but when i do the same thing with web UI ,server is loaded once so the hibernate class and spring classes,resultant getting the same value instead of everytime executing the getAllEmployee().Does the value stored in some cache ? if yes how to make them disabled,i didn't mention any cache explicitly in my pozo clases

Comment: From the tagging it looks like you are using Spring Data w/ JPA.  Usually, at least in all the setups I have seen, JPA has some underlying ORM (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc) behind it.  If this is the case, then there could definitely be some sort of caching at play.  Second, not sure why you are reading your domain objects then converting them to some BO object.  Is there some reason you are doing this?  Could this conversion perhaps be the issue?  Can you hook up a debugger, put a break point in your DAO after you retrieve the list, then in your service after conversion to the BOs?

Comment: @CodeChimp using BO is the funtional requirement i am using service layer for that,and regarding debugging employeeBO  object contain the previous value instead of new value its not collection the data from database its collectiing the data from some cache i am not able to figure it out how to remove this problem

Comment: Do you have a two-way relationship between the "parent" and "child" domain objects?  If so, are you cleaning up both sides of the relationship when you delete the parent?

Comment: @CodeChimp no only oneto many from dept to employee for the sake of confusion i am adding pozo of dept and employee

Comment: And, when you look at the tables, ALL of the IDs are cleaned up?  With a OneToMany relationship, what I would expect to see is the "employee" table have a foreign key to the "department" table.  One of of the instances where you are having this issue, can you take the ID of the Department and do something like : select * from employee where department_id = XXX; --(where XXX is the ID of the department you are checking)

Comment: @CodeChimp yes in database all the departmentId is cleaned up . i have mentioned that its properly reflected on database when i delete the department, then departmentid is set to null in employee table department_id column problem is that when i again call getallEmployee() method  then in jsp page its showing previous value instead of null value when i restart the server then it shows null value properly in jsp page. for Your consideration what i have done on repository i m pasting it.

Comment: I only ask because I have myself written code where I thought I cleaned up a relationship, but I only partially cleaned it up, or worse, had the Cascading wrong so the update was never reflected in the DB at all.  As a test, can you do this: Reproduce the problem, then shut down the server and restart it completely.  Is the problem still there?  If it is, then it would point to something not quite write in the data.  If it is not, it would, in my opinion, point to caching.  At that point, I would ask to see how your JPA was setup up.